# Why does a bytes object converts to int when get only one byte?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

Behaviour is showed in the code:

```
>>> b = bytes(b'asdf')
>>> print(type(b))
<class 'bytes'>
>>> print(type(b[0]))
<class 'int'>
```

Why when I get one byte from the bytes object like this `b[0]`, it converts it to int.

Comment: use slice to get it as bytes `type(b[:0])`

Comment: you have the same with list `a = [1,2,3]` - `type(a)` gives `<class 'list'>`  and `type(a[0])` gives `<class 'int'>` instead of `<class 'list'>` but `type(a[:0])` still gives `<class 'list'>`. Maybe the same is with `bytes` - it may means `"list of integers"` and when y

Comment: This is the expected and [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) behavior: "bytes objects actually behave like immutable sequences of integers, with each value in the sequence restricted such that 0 <= x < 256"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bytes()` function returns a bytes object. So, `b` in your example is an immutable sequence of bytes. Each element of the sequence is unsigned int and accessible via index.